# Как извлечь Авторизацию из webBrowser

Tags: c#, авторизация, webbrowser

Здравствуйте!

Есть проблема в проекте, Нужно авторизация на сайте через `webBrowser`, `WebClient` и `HtmlAgilityPack` не могут сами пройти Basic авторизацию. Вхожу на сайт через `webBrowser`, а дальше не нужно грузить все элементы, а только `html` текст, поэтому загружаю через `System.Net.WebClient` добавляя заголовки `Authorization` и `Cookie`.

```
string Autoriz = "Basic XXxxXXxxXXxxXXxxXXxx==";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, Autoriz);
```

А как этот заголовок авторизации использовать из webBrowser?

P.S. Дебагером уже перековырял весь `webBrowser` и не нашёл, а также Google не помог.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте еще прописать хеддер юзерагента, который поддерживает куки.

Comment: ничего не могу найти, только через сторонний перехват заголовков.